# How to use a relative path for pdo_mysql.default_socket in php.ini?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo

Is there a way to use a relative path for pdo_mysql.default_socket ? What would this path be relative to ?

Comment: You forgot one more question: Why one would need a relative path for this?

Comment: Indeed :) Because I'd like to put everything related to apache / mysql / php (such as php.ini, httpd.conf, my.cnf) in a subfolder of my project, and the mysql socket too. But it would be useful only if it could be "portable", meaning not having the full path in the php.ini file.

Comment: well, why don't just try to put that socket in your relative directory and see if it works?

Comment: I tried... MySQL works fine, and in my.cnf, "socket" is relative to "datadir". In php.ini, I wonder if the "*_socket" paths are relative to another value.

Comment: Just thought I could search PHP source for that :) https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=pdo_mysql.default_socket&ref=cmdform. I'm on a lead !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to pass a directive as an argument when starting httpd, so that you can use whatever path at runtime. You **must** use php_admin_value, php_value won't work :

```
httpd -c "php_admin_value pdo_mysql.default_socket /path/to/socket"
```